# Swap used but there is free RAM

Tags: memory, swap

I am surprised to see my Ubuntu 20.04 using swap as there is 700G in buffers/cache.

It has never done this before.

Is something wrong?

I feel like it should return RAM used in buffers/cache to be free prior to using swap.

```
# cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
0
# cat /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure
100
```

```
# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1007         239          18         298         749         462
Swap:           566         138         428
```

Answer (score 0):

No, paging out is not wrong. Linux will use swap space given to it.

[swappiness](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) of 0 and swapping indicates "the amount of free and file-backed pages is less than the high water mark in a zone".  This may have happened some time previously under more memory pressure than you observe now.

Linux is not in a hurry to free up used swap space, even after paging some of it back into physical RAM. Those are pages that could be reclaimed if needed in the future.